# How does the LOAD CSV in neo4j work exactly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When we use the load csv (in cypher) in neo4j and then write a few match or merge or create statements after that, what exactly happens on the backend ? I am guessing that the same series of matches and other statements are executed again and again for each row in the CSV. The key part of my understanding is that, every time this series of statements are executed (for each row in csv), the data that the is searched for, is the updated one after the last execution of statements for the previous csv row. But I have come across a problem in using this and it contradicts with this belief. So I would really appreciate if anyone can help with this.

### EDIT :

The problem is something like this :

1) Let's say there are just 2 rows in a CSV with 3 columns, The three columns are 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Preference'. I also have a node in the DB with label 'Person'
2) Now I want to iterate over this CSV and create a node for all distinct Preferneces in the CSV. While I am doing so, I also want to maintain a relation between the node of label 'Person' and his preferences. The startDate and endDate are basically times in java milliseconds format. This indicates the time range when a person had some kind of 'preference'. So, what I am doing actually is

```
LOAD CSV  WITH HEADERS FROM 'file_location' as row
    MATCH (a:PERSON{name:'X'}) 
    WITH a, row
    MERGE (c:Preference{value: row.Preference}) 
    WITH row, c, a
    OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[prevRelation:hasPreference{endDate:253402318799000}]->(:PREFERENCE) 
    WITH row, prevRelation, a, c  
    MERGE (a)-[currRelation: hasPreference]->(c) 
    ON CREATE SET currRelation.startDate = row.StartDate,
       currRelation.endDate = 253402318799000, 
       prevRelation.endDate = row.StartDate - 1000
    ON MATCH SET prevRelation.lastRefreshed = row.StartDate - 1000
```

253402318799000 - For my case, indicates end of time.

EXPLANATION :

(i) Match the 'PERSON' node with a particular property value - MATCH

(ii) Merge on the 'PREFERENCE' label node with a particular property value - MERGE

(iii) See if relation with a particular property exists (this property is indicative of latest preference of the person) between the two nodes in (i) and (ii) - OPTIONAL MATCH

(iv) If the relation exists, there is current/latest relation and I will have it in a variable 'prevRelation' if not, it will be null

(v) Now, do a merge on  nodes from (i) and (ii) and see if the same relation exists without the property

(vi) ON create, I set a few properties for previous relation, basically setting its endTime and then setting up properties for newly created relation - This means that there was not a relation between the preference and the person

(vii) ON Match, I update the properties for the relation i.e. the last refreshed time - This means there was a relation between the preference and the person

Comment: Your understanding is basically correct. Your question needs to provide full details about the "problem" that you came across if you expect more help.

Comment: @cybersam Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: @ToreEschliman: if it is the case that I cannot query anything that is created while iterating through the CSV, then how come I am able to grab the nodes created by the merge ?

Comment: The `OPTIONAL MATCH` uses the `PREFERENCE` label, when the previous `MERGE` uses `Preference`: the case matters. Is that a typo in the recreation of the query or did you just copy/paste that query? You should really provide a real, tested query (with the CSV data as well) so people can reproduce it easily. Otherwise, it's much more cumbersome to debug.